# Connect to Azure Windows 2012 server using OpenVPN Fail

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, openvpn, azure

I have installed and configured OpenVPN on Azure Windows 2012 R2 Server.
The azure server has an Azure virtual network associated. I have added port 1194 into Inbound rules and switched off windows firewall.
I try to connect to the server from my home computer the connection get right but the vpn doesn’t work 
I can’t ping the vpn gateway from home computer (ping 10.10.0.1) and I can’t ping home computer from the server (ping 10.10.0.6). The results in both ends are “Requested time out”.
This all configuration was moved from on-premise network to azure. It worked fine.
It seems like Azure filtring OpenVPN traffic packets.
has anybody had same problem with azure?? Or Do I need any extra configuration on Azure.
I hope someone can help me.
Thanks.
Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It seems like Azure filtring OpenVPN traffic packets. has anybody had
>   same problem with azure?

We can deploy openvpn in azure VM, Azure will not block openvpn traffic packets.

> Do I need any extra configuration on Azure.

In Azure, we should add inbound rules to NSG, if your use default port 1194, we should add 1194 to NSG's inbound rules.

For test, can you check your route entries, maybe we can add some route entries.
Please check your openvpn client get the virtual IP address or not.
Besides, to troubleshoot this issue more efficiently, you may try to perform a network capture on the client and server. Then we are able to find the detailed behavior of the client and server, which is very useful for further troubleshooting.

===================================
**Update**:
For test, I have create two VMs on Azure, different Vnet.
Server: public IP: 52.179.17.232  internal IP: 10.0.0.4  openvpn IP: 10.8.0.1
Client: Public IP: 52.179.5.224   internal IP: 10.0.1.4  openvpn IP: 10.8.0.6
NSG settings, open port 1194 for openvpn server:[image]

Here is my client screenshot, please check it:[image]

**Update2**:
Also I had test with my local server, it works fine. I deploy the client in my lab, here is the screenshot:[image][image]

Comment: Hi @Jason Ye - MSFT As I comment you into the main text I have already created the inbound rule for udp 1194 port. If I remove this entry the vpn not even get connect. Furthermore  I have captured the network packet in both ends and using wireshark but I cant find the problem.  Have you ever deployed OPENVpn in Azure. ?? Thank you very mucho for your help.
Regards.

Comment: @AndresCorallo yes, I have deploy openvpn on Azure, it works fine. for test  I create two VMs in different Vnets, one for server, another is client, just open port 1194 for server NSG, then configure openvpn, after complete, client can connect to openvpn server. I have update my answer with the screenshot, please check it. by the way, I follow this link to deploy openvpn, maybe you can follow this link to deploy openvpn.http://blog.bobbyallen.me/2016/02/07/setting-up-openvpn-server-on-windows-2012-r2/

Comment: @AndresCorallo "The results in both ends are “Requested time out”" maybe we should check the error logs, there are something wrong with the openvpn settings.

Comment: @AndresCorallo  Does it work now? what can I do for you?

Comment: Hi @@Jason Ye - MSFT. Are the Cliente and Server on Azure network .?? In my case the server is in Azure and the clients are on internet (out side from Azure networks). How is your deploy?? Thanks very much for all youe help.

Comment: @AndresCorallo yes, I deploy them in different Vnets, the client settings same as on-prem, the client can't connect to server without VPN. I will deploy the client out of Azure, please wait for a while.

Comment: @AndresCorallo I have test in my lab, I deploy client in my Hyper-v, and the server create in Azure VM, after configure it completed, I can connect to the server, I have update my answer, please check it. please check you r client and server's openvpn logs, there are something wrong with your configure, also you can post your error logs here, which is very useful for further troubleshooting.

Comment: Hi @@Jason Ye - MSFT. There are no erros  on either server or client logs and the conexion is perfect. Just the traffic between to points dosnt' work. Thanks for your help

Comment: @AndresCorallo please try use tcping tool to test your client to server connection, use tcping tool we should open port 80 on NSG, we can download it from here,https://www.elifulkerson.com/projects/tcping.php  also you can send your client config file and server config file to me. by the way, if tcping is ok, you may try to perform a network capture on the server and client,

Comment: Hi @@Jason Ye - MSFT. I can solve the problem. It was an uncaptibility IP Version. I just deleted comp lzo entry into client configuration file and then work fine. Thank you very much for all your help. :)

Comment: @AndresCorallo Glad to here your issue have solved, if my answer is helpful, please accept it as an answer, thanks:)